# Slide Deck not displaying properly in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have installed the free version of [Slide Deck](http://www.slidedeck.com), a jQuery slider on a [Wordpress website](http://www.louisbaxters.com.au/).

It displays fine in Internet Explorer 8 and Firefox 5, but does not slide or display properly in Google Chrome.

In Chrome, the slider merges into the content below it.

In IE8 & FF5, there is empty space below the slider corresponding to where the images would normally be displayed if they were not in the slider.

[image: Slide Deck not displaying properly in Chrome]

(the contact info displays below the image in IE8 and FF5, not overlayed as with Chrome)

If I place the slider inside a div with a height equal to the height of 1 image, it fixes the empty space in IE8 & FF5, but doubles the problem in Chrome.

[image: Slide Deck not displaying properly in Chrome]

Any ideas why Chrome doesn't like this?

Answer (score 1):

It actually works absolutely fine if you access the site again.

The reason for the above behaviour is that slider script (`$('.slidedeck')...`) simply not get initialized. It's the same as if JavaScript is disabled.

If you check **Console** panel in Google Chrome's Developer tools, you will see this kind of message:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://s7.addthis.com/static/r07/sh46.html#iit=1311067124513&cb=0&ab=-&dh=www.louisbaxters.com.au&dr=&du=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.louisbaxters.com.au%2F&dt=Louis%20Baxter%C2%A0%7C%C2%A0Coffee%20in%20Subiaco&inst=1&lng=en-GB&pc=wpp&pub=ra-4e25011e4930aecb&ssl=0&sid=4e254bf4fe18466d&srd=1&srf=0.02&srp=0.2&srx=0.5&ver=250&xck=0&rev=102311&ct=1&xd=1
>   from frame with URL http://www.louisbaxters.com.au/. Domains,
>   protocols and ports must match.

It looks like this error prevents slider from working in Chrome.

If I visit the same page once again I see no such message in Console and slider works fine.

What I would suggest, is to move your slider initialization code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` instead of having it executed in the middle of the page.

Comment: What do you mean by accessing the site again?  Refresh the page?  Come back in 10 minutes?  In both cases it still displays the same bug.  I will look at making the change you suggested.  Thanks.

Comment: I made the change to the initialisation code, and it works fine in Firefox, but the same issue is occuring in Chrome, although the console error is gone.

It was strange with Chrome.  After the change, loaded the page; it wasn't working, I look away, looked back at Chrome, and it was sliding properly.  I refreshed the page, and then the slider broke as it did initially.

Comment: @Steve With the new change it starts Slider code when whole page is fully initialized. So, if there is a delay with AddThis code, the slider will not start until it will be resolved (successfully or not). The main thing -- it is working now (compared to previous completely broken situation). I recommend removing AddThis code and run a test. I'm sure there will be a difference. _"What do you mean by accessing the site again?"_ Not refresh, but clicking Home link again (or any other way where NO full refresh is needed).

Comment: @Steve To get rid of overlayed moment, I recommend adding `overflow: hidden;` to `#slidedeckdiv` CSS definition -- this will hide other images when JavaScript is not available / Slider is not yet initialized. You may also adjust height from 270 to 265.